# Maven war packaging creating multiple version of the same SNAPSHOT jars in WEB-INF/lib

Tags: maven-3

To get a *war* we do:

```
mvn clean
mvn package
```

Now we have a *war*. The `WEB-INF/lib` in this has duplicate `SNAPSHOT`s like these:

```
xyz-0.4.0-20111110.152222-176.jar
xyz-0.4.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

I have no idea why *xyz-0.4.0-20111110.152222-176.jar* is getting included.

This is happening for all my dependencies. We have a local nexus installation.

The *pom.xml* is very ordinary. It only has dependency for *xyz-0.4.0-SNAPSHOT*, and no plugin section!

Comment: Without knowning the exact content of your pom is not possible to give a good advice...Which maven version are you using? Is this a multimodule project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although i don't know exactly what the problem was, i solved it as follows:

In my pom.xml i had reference to a dependency i.e a jar (which has a pom.xml within it too). For some reason that was causing problems. When i removed this dependency, the problem went away. Although i need this particular dependency!

Anyways, thats what i know for now.

Comment: our fix for this was that somehow [mistakenly] we had a dependency "on itself" (of <type>war</type> though that may be unrelated) which was causing it to basically load all version of dependencies into the WEB-INF/lib.  Removing the dependency fixed it.
Weird.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to make sure you're running the 'clean' goal. I also was just confused why my war's WEB-INF/lib directory had multiple versions of the same jar (one of my project's dependencies) in it. I needed to clean.

Answer (score -1):

Depending on the pom structure I found several workarounds to solve similar problems:

- In https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MWAR-220 it is stated that removing the dependencyManagement section is working when working with war overlays.
- Someone removed the dependency plugin to solve the problem. (edit 2016: unfortunately the forum does not contain the answers any more:
  http://www.tikalk.com/alm/forums/maven-war-plugin-picking-multiple-version-same-snapshot-jars)
- I excluded the transitive dependency that produced the duplicate entry in the dependency section of my war pom and kept the dependency plugin.